# Aligning a combination of strings in Python

Tags: python, format, alignment

I know that in Python, to align a string within a certain width, one can use a format string. For example, the following code prints the centered the string 'Readability counts' at 30 spaces wide:

```
print "{0: ^30}".format("Readability counts")
```

Now I would like to center the string "2 + 4", but I'd like to build it up out of two attributes of the same object (`obj.atr1` and `obj.atr2`).

I could first combine the two values to form one string (either using concatenation or formatting) and then pass that one on to the next format string, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of dealing with this. Preferably, I'd use just *one* format operation, as this would allow me to just pass `obj` as an argument and get the attributes out using the format string. Something along the lines of the following..

```
print "{0.atr1} + {0.atr2}".format(obj)
```

.. but then with centering added to it.

I know it works when I do something like this..

```
print "{0: ^30}".format("{0.atr1} + {0.atr2}".format(obj))
```

.. but that is quite inconvenient if I were to want to use other attributes of `obj` in the leftmost format strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last approach seems sensible, you still can use other `obj` attributes passing it once again:

```
print "{0: ^30} | {1.atr3}".format("{0.atr1} + {0.atr2}".format(obj), obj)
```

Comment: Fair enough, I'll just go with that.